# Render-blocking JavaScript & CSS - Google PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, css

This is my code for the CSS but after saving my site got messed up, did I paste something in wrong? I also have one JavaScript file that is under remove render-blocking JavaScript in the Google PageSpeed results. The below code is pasted in my header.

```html
<script>
var cb = function() {
var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.href = '<?= site_url() ?>third_party_plugins/dist/css/style.css';
l.href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
l.href = '<?= site_url() ?>resources/css/custom.css';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
};
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the code above just before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var l = document.getElementByTag('head');
l.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<link href="<?= site_url() ?>third_party_plugins/dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'+'<link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' + '<link href="<?= site_url() ?>third_party_plugins/dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
```

Try this instead of

```
var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.href = '<?= site_url() ?>third_party_plugins/dist/css/style.css';
l.href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
l.href = '<?= site_url() ?>resources/css/custom.css';
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
};
```